# Clojure - Using recursion to find the number of elements in a list

Tags: list, recursion, clojure

I have written a function that uses recursion to find the number of elements in a list and it works successfully however, I don't particularly like the way I've written it. Now I've written it one way I can't seem to think of a different way of doing it.

My code is below:

```
(def length 
 (fn [n]
  (loop [i n total 0]
   (cond (= 0 i) total
     :t (recur (rest i)(inc total))))))
```

To me it seems like it is over complicated, can anyone think of another way this can be written for comparison?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/count?

Comment: I have to make it work using recursion which is why I have gone down the route of using a loop and why it's ended up so complicated. Would using count recursively make sense?

Comment: Using `loop-recur` you just have a loop, not recursion.

Comment: loop/recur is the same thing conceptually as a recursive function - it's why "recur" is part of the name. It's implemented on the JVM as a loop, but if you ported it to scheme you'd implement it with a recursive function.

Comment: @amalloy, I think one should point out that scheme has [TailCall-Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) required by its standard, so if I'm not mistaken your "implementation as a recursive function" would most likley end up with a loop and as such be identical to a explicit tail-call via a keyword (like `recur` is). - except it's automaticlly done

Comment: Of course. The point is that, using the terminology from SICP, you're writing a recursive procedure, which will execute as an iterative process. The fact that there are ways to perform the operation without using up a bunch of stack space doesn't cause the definition to not be recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a naive recursive version:

```
(defn my-count [coll]
    (if (empty? coll) 
        0 
        (inc (my-count (rest coll)))))
```

Bear in mind there's not going to be any tail call optimization going on here so for long lists the stack will overflow.

Here is a version using `reduce`:

```
(defn my-count [coll]
    (reduce (fn [acc x] (inc acc)) 0 coll))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is code showing some different solutions. Normally, you should use the built-in function `count`.

```
(def data [:one :two :three])

(defn count-loop [data]
  (loop [cnt 0
         remaining data]
    (if (empty? remaining)
      cnt
      (recur (inc cnt) (rest remaining)))))

(defn count-recursive [remaining]
    (if (empty? remaining)
      0
      (inc (count-recursive (rest remaining)))))

(defn count-imperative [data]
  (let [cnt (atom 0)]
    (doseq [elem data]
      (swap! cnt inc))
    @cnt))

(deftest t-count
  (is (= 3 (count data)))
  (is (= 3 (count-loop data)))
  (is (= 3 (count-recursive data)))
  (is (= 3 (count-imperative data))))
```

Comment: Why even mention how to do this with an atom? It's an antipattern anyone would argue against; if you wanted to add a third approach to the other two good approaches, reduce would be the function to showcase.

Comment: Sometimes an imperative/mutable approach is the simplest answer (everything but `count` is overkill for this example, obviously). If code nobody can see is imperative or mutable, and it doesn't leak out, why worry about it? Everything is mutable/imperative if you dig deep enough. Only when it leaks out does it become a problem.

Comment: That's a very Turing-machine-oriented way of thinking. Alternatively you could say, everything is recursive if you dig deep enough (lambda calculus). Only when you have to actually implement it on a modern physical processor in real life do the imperative implementation details leak out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that is tail-call optimized, and doesn't rely on `loop`. Basically the same as Alan Thompson's first one, but inner functions are the best things. (And feel more idiomatic to me.) :-)

```
(defn my-count [sq]
 (letfn [(inner-count [c s]
          (if (empty? s) 
           c
           (recur (inc c) (rest s))))]
  (inner-count 0 sq)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here is another twist

```
(defn my-count
  ([data]
   (my-count data 0))
  ([data counter]
   (if (empty? data)
     counter
     (recur (rest data) (inc counter)))))
```